# Динамические поддомены nginx

Tags: nginx

Как сделать в nginx из site.ru/folder folder.site.ru примеров целая куча, а что если нет директорий, и поддомены нужно создавать на лету из get запроса?

Помогите сделать из такой конструкции: **site.ru/index.php?id=999** такую **999.site.ru**

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, что в данном случае скорее подойдёт модуль [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) для nginx.